# Are Unique Props Per Mongo Document Bad Form or Performance Degrading?

Tags: json, database, mongodb, data-structures

Mongo is new for me and I want to do strange things with its freedom but don't want to cause myself problems down the road. Say I have a collection of things. I want to store alternate names of these things for easy lookup of the normal name. The client knows the alternate name and wants to know the normal name. This is what I am doing and wonder if I should do something else instead:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1ace96e629e2aab338fe7f"),
    "Spade" : "Shovel"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1ace9ae629e2aab338fe80"),
    "Digger" : "Shovel"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1ace9be629e2aab338fe81"),
    "Large Trowel" : "Shovel"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1aceb3e629e2aab338fe82"),
    "ball peen" : "hammer"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1aceb7e629e2aab338fe83"),
    "gavel" : "hammer"
}
```

Should data like this instead be stored in this fashion:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1ace96e629e2aab338fe7f"),
    "alternateName" : "spade",
    "normalName" : "shovel"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1ace9ae629e2aab338fe80"),
    "alternateName" : "digger",
    "normalName" : "shovel"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1ace9be629e2aab338fe81"),
    "alternateName" : "Large Trowel",
    "normalName" : "shovel"
}
```

This is very simplistic made up data. I basically want a map structure that I can access a value from very quickly with a known key. Are there performance losses or other obvious problems with this?

Comment: man.... where is the MongoDB community?